# issue with multiple custom choose file

Tags: javascript, html

**this is my code i want more than 1 custom choose file upload in place of this label**

```
<form>
<input type="file" id="file-upload" multiple required />
<image for="file-upload">Upload file</>
<div id="file-upload-filename"></div>
```

input[type="file"] { 
       z-index: -1;
       position: absolute;
       opacity: 0;
       }

```
   input:focus + label {
  outline: 2px solid;
   }
  <script>
  var input = document.getElementById( 'file-upload' );
  var infoArea = document.getElementById( 'file-upload-filename' );

  input.addEventListener( 'change', showFileName );

  function showFileName( event ) {


   var input = event.srcElement;

   var fileName = input.files[0].name;

   infoArea.textContent = 'File name: ' + fileName;
          }
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `<label>` instead of `<image>` maybe?

Comment: yes but i want more than 1 choose file upload label or button

Comment: https://codepen.io/hidde/pen/LyLmrG for example this code i want more than 1 choose file label or image in my table